# how can I create a link with element.appendChild

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, appendchild

I'm using the following Javascript code in order to extract an information from the current webpage through an extension. I posted only partial and relevant code because all is very long, I have no issue with this code, I get the company name in output on the current page with no issue. Now, I need that the same text comes to output as a link "", so that I can click on it and open the webpage I link to this text. I suppose I should change element.appendChild(organ); but I have no idea how to make it a link. Would you mind to suggest me something? Please ask for more details if you need. Thank you very much in advance.

```js
var enrollmentField = $('input[class="inputField-textBox"]');

var getOrg = $(enrollmentField[0]).val();
var newOrg = "<span class='greyc'>" + getOrg + "</span>";

var organ = document.createTextNode("Organization: "); element.appendChild(organ);

document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(organ); $(newOrg).appendTo('#myList');
```

Comment: what is `element`

Comment: that is the following: var element = document.createElement("p");

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orgInput = document.getElementById('organisation'),
a = document.getElementById('a');

function setA(){
  a.innerText = orgInput.value;
  a.href = orgInput.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="organisation">
<input type="button" onclick="setA()" value="create"/>
<a id="a"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
let anchorText = document.createTextNode("Organization name");
a.appendChild(anchorText);
a.title = "Open organization webpage";
a.href = "http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve in this way and works:

```js
orglink = "<a href='" + webSite + "' target='_blank'>" + newOrg + "</a>";
```

Thank you very much for your help guys.